# LuaJIT equivalent of wlua.exe

Tags: windows, lua, luajit

In Windows, I want to know if there is an equivalent way of using LuaJIT like the standard Lua distribution wlua.exe, which is windowless. 
Or should I compile the modules and use them in a standard Lua interpreter? (not sure if this is possible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, since LuaJIT is [ABI-compatible](http://luajit.org/extensions.html) with Lua 5.1, you can swap `lua51.dll` and `lua5.1.dll` out, and replace them with the LuaJIT version of `lua51.dll`. Just copy LuaJIT's `lua51.dll` into the folder with `wlua.exe` and make another copy named `lua5.1.dll`. That should cover everything.

This should be possible with any application that dynamically links to Lua 5.1.

Comment: Like a charm! Thank you, I am just beginning to have fun with Lua!

Comment: The only difference between `wlua.exe` and `lua.exe` is that the former has `subsystem:windows` rather than `subsystem:console` specified at link time. As a result Windows chooses to not automatically associate it with a console, and does not create a console window to associate it to. When you decide you need your own distinct `.exe` file to hold up a private icon and other branding resources, you can easily do the same thing. I've often found it handy to keep a console build around for debugging even when shipping a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

LuaDist comes with a `wluajit.exe`